# Only one module for 2 Mac plugin bundles (AU, VST) gets loaded

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-audio, audiounit, vst

my audio plugins are bundles with binaries containing exports for all supported formats, say AU and VST. I copy the exact same bundle (just different extension) to

```
/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components for AU
and
/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST for VST
```

Now when user opens say the VST plugin, it works fine. But when he opens the AU plugin afterwards it crashes and from the stack trace it looks like a complete mess one module calling the other etc. I originally thought it's the good old Cocoa global classname, being the huge Mac OS X design flaw, but it seems it's not the case, because the VST uses Carbon.

It seems it doesn't load the AU module at all, it just created another component from the VST module, just with AU interface! I have a global variable in there, so I logged its address and it's the same for both plugins, so it must be the same module, right?

Unfortunately I need really the right one loaded for each, because they have different initialization and globals. So how can I make OS load the second one properly?

Thanks!